# What is the best way to match packets across pcap files from different capture points?

Tags: ip, networking, packet-analysis, pcap

I have multiple pcap files which contain data from different capture points in the network.

Previously I thought that by using the IP-ID field I can match the packets across the capture files but I discovered that is not a reliable way of doing it.

I am looking for a solution that would work for both TCP and UDP.

Comment: TCP creates connections that are identified by the source and destination IP and TCP addresses. While UDP does not have connections, the same information can be used, but you cannot guarantee that it is the same conversation.

Comment: Thanks but I am trying to match packets not conversations

Comment: You first need to narrow down the packets to the connections, then you can compare them. Packets not in the same connection will not match. In any case, I really do not see how this is a network engineering problem. You probably want to find an application that can help you, but such recommendations are explicitly off-topic.

Comment: I am trying to code this myself. I thought it would be a network engineering problem since its purely related to networking right?

Comment: No, not everything related to networking is a network engineering problem. This is not something that network engineers would do in the normal course of business. Normally, we would use something like NetFlow (IPFIX) to gather statistics, but trying to match individual packets across a network seems rather pointless.

Comment: Please if you do not find any usage for something do not call it pointless. One thing that can be usefull for is to discover if there is packet loss across different segments of the network and how many are lost, also for delay on the network.

Comment: We have other tools for that that work quite well without needing to match individual packets. This is not something that seems to serve any purpose for network engineering.

Comment: Ok please if you have nothing usefull to add go on with your business thank you.

Comment: Are you essentially de-duplicating packets from your multiple captures?  This is a tough problem.

I would consider that there may be one best capture location within your network for each destination IP address.  Capture locations topologically further away might capture a few more packets (lost en-route) but are less likely to capture all packets from all sources toward the destination.  Therefore, I would decide which capture location is best for each IP.

Comment: @JeffWheeler sadly I cannot decide where to capture. I just have the pcaps that are put on the network. For TCP I guess I could use the conversation info plus the sequence number info, but I dont know how it could be done for UDP. Is hashing an option?

Comment: Maybe you can explain your use-case in more detail.  You mentioned packet loss and latency measurement; if that's what you're doing, you don't need to match *every* packet; you just need to search for the presence/absence of some packets.  I'm having a hard time figuring out what your need really is.  If you can add more detail to your original question, perhaps this will help.